# Lodash how to short circuit terminate

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Is there a way to have Lodash terminate early such that this returns true instead of throwing exception?

```
_.chain([i => 'a', 0])
.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.concat(curr()), [])
.some(i => i == 'a')
.value()
```

Comment: A little more detail on whats throwing an exception, and where things go wromng in your code....

Comment: i => 'a' is a function, 0 is not. When curr() is executed upon 0, it throws an exception. I would desire that .some() is evaluated on i => 'a' before attempting to continue reducing.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you use lodash for that? Why not just `[i => 'a', 0].some(item => typeof item === 'function' && item() === 'a')`?

Comment: thats not how reduce and some work. reduce always returns an array and some always takes an array. if you want to check on results before continuing you need a stream for this

Comment: @NicolasGehlert reduce does *not* always return an array https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce It's the blind leading the blind around here

Comment: @GeorgeJempty true, but reduce will always return a "finished" value. always return an object/array/number/string. never return a "stream" that you can intercept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe actually I'm thinking about the problem incorrectly, if the answer I'm wanting is the boolean result of .some(), then that should be my highest order query.

```
_.chain([i => 'a', 0])
.some(i => i() == 'a')
.value();
```

Then it evaluates the first item first and quits early. Expecting a Lodash specific answer is non-useful.

Comment: well if you can avoid the reduce all together sure the some works as you want to. I just assumed that is simplified and you cannot get rid of the reduce. Also in your example lodash again makes everything more complex and complicated :D [i => 'a', 0]).some(i => i() == 'a') does the same. no need for additional wrappers

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code is really hard to read and the use of _.chain is not really needed.

Your functions throws an error because you try to call a function on your second entry in the array with curr().

Everything you want to achieve in your result you can do without lodash.

```
const values = [i => 'a', 0];

const filtered = values.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  if (typeof curr === 'function') {
    prev.push(curr());
  } else {
    prev.push(curr);
  }

  return prev;
}, []);

const hasSpecificValue = filtered.some(i => i == 'a');

console.log(hasSpecificValue);
```

Here I added a jsfiddle for example

https://jsfiddle.net/fhk7q0uf/6/

If you just want to fix your code, either remove the 0 entry or add a separate check to the reduce function. Could look like this

```
_.chain([i => 'a', 0])
.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.concat(typeof curr === 'function' ? curr() : curr), [])
.some(i => i == 'a')
.value()
```

Comment: Apologies for the unclear code. I guess my question isn't such to get this specific trivial example to work, but if there's a way in a generic sense to have it short circuit. Such that it first reduces i => 'a' to 'a', then evaluates .some('a' == 'a') and returns true avoiding having to reduce the remainder of array.

Comment: yeah as i wrote in my previous comment thats not how reduce or some functions work. They don't work in streams. You'll always need to have the entire result. Maybe generator functions help you if you really want to achieve this: https://blog.jeremyfairbank.com/javascript/functional-javascript-streams-2/

Comment: may I ask for what reason you want to have the "short circuit" ?

Comment: Was hoping to avoid needing to write a generator, but you're probably correct that that may be the only way to handle it as-is. It would need to process as a stream. The purpose is to avoid unnecessary computation of the reducer. For example, If I had a generator that returned a never ending list of items, I would need a way to apply .some() early as it would never finish reducing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `transform` instead of `reduce`.

> Iteratee functions may exit iteration early by explicitly returning false.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#transform

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for lazy evaluation.
It exists for some methods that are listed in docs for [lodash wrapper](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#lodash) - check `.some` is not chainable by default.

Also `reduce()` cannot be lazy evaluated since `reduce()` may/can/will affect all the its result at *each* step(or am I wrong on that point?).

```
_([(i) => 'a', 0])
  .map(x=> x())
  .filter(x => x === 'a')
  .slice(0, 1)
  .value()
```

works almost as you asked(except that fact `.slice` returns `undefined` instead of boolean False in case there was no such an element)